# azure service bus azure function or http request to add message

Tags: azure, http, azure-functions, queue, azureservicebus

I have multiple systems that need to integrate data into another system. I'm considering using Azure Service Bus to place messages in a queue and process them. I'm wondering what would be the optimal approach: Should I use an Azure Function to enqueue messages, or should I have the various systems send messages directly to the queue using HTTP requests?

I believe Azure Functions could be the best approach to gain better control over each request

Answer (score 0):

Azure Functions route is likely to be the simplest and most secure option from what you've listed. While it's possible for each producer to send messages directly to the Azure Service Bus namespace, it's better to keep it to the minimum who can have direct access. An HTTP Function could validate access and convert the request payload into a message.

In case you have API Management in place, it could also be used to convert HTTP requests made to a defined endpoint, and send those as Service Bus messages.

Comment: Hi Sean, thanks for your response. I agree regarding security, but I have a question about performance. Do you think that an Azure Function, which places messages in a queue, performs equivalently to an HTTP request in terms of the Service Bus's performance?

Comment: Going straight to ASB is always more performant than having something in the middle. But ask yourself a question what will you do when a security issue arises? Replacing ASB connection string on every producer? Do you control those? Can you even enforce the connection string change? Performance is important but I would not compromise the security for a few milliseconds.